# How to change app title in "Task Menu" Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, scaffold

When enter task menu(android), it shows "Flutter Demo" instead of my app label string in Manifest xml file. In the screen pages, I used scaffold with no app bar, hence no title, but there's safe area widget inside.

Where shall I edit in order to have custom app tile name.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MaterialApp()` you have `title` property. You should change it in there.

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'HERE GOES YOUR TITLE',
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('MaterialApp Theme'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for replying. I may not want appbar. So I just need to omit the AppBar out right? Will try...and is material app applicable for statefulwidget or only stateless?

Comment: Yes, just omit the AppBar. Both. It has to be at the root of your app

Answer (score 0):

first of all use MaterialApp Widget and warp your whole Widget tree in MaterialApp widget

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'your app name',
  home: Scaffold(
```

then edit name and description property in pubspec.yaml

```
name: your app name
description: your app description
```

then chnage `android:label` in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:label="your application name"
```

after all run `flutter clean` command and then `flutter build`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try changing the name in pubspec.yaml file also like this
```

1) Open pubspec.yaml file.

2 Scroll to top .

3) change the name field to your app name which want to set

4) and set tile like this also

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'your app name',
  home: Scaffold(
```

[image]